How to allow Google Calendar API in React Application to access one specific Calendar and get event information using React Typescript
Good afternoon,
I am currently working on one of my first bigger React Typescript projects since I got started. In this application I am making there is supposed to be a calendar at the bottom of the fist page which displays Events coming from a personal Calendar. This means that when any user opens the page, they should not be requested to log into any Google related stuff but instead the calendar at the bottom should simply display the events from my personal calendar. Below if the current structure of my Calendar component and everything I have been able to do to at least authenticate myself within the Google API. Would very much appreciate it if someone could show me how to properly finish getting the information.
All examples I have seen online require the users to log in but the user should never have to enter anything. Please allow me to know what I have to do next or what I am missing if possible.
Thank you!
Google API Loader:
// useGapiLoader.ts
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useGapiLoader = (
  apiKey: string,
  clientId: string,
  discoveryDocs: string[],
  scope: string,
  onLoaded: () => void
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    function ass() {
      window.gapi.client
        .init({
          apiKey,
          discoveryDocs,
          clientId,
          scope,
        })
        .then(function () {
          return (gapi.client as any).people.people.get({
            resourceName: "people/me",
            "requestMask.includeField": "person.names",
          });
        })
        .then(
          function (response) {
            console.log(response.result);
          },

          function (reason) {
            console.log("Error: " + reason.result.error.message);
          }
        );
    }

    window.gapi.load("client", ass);

    // Load the gapi script if it's not already loaded
  }, [apiKey, clientId, discoveryDocs, scope, onLoaded]);
};

export default useGapiLoader;

Layout.tsx:
"use client";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Footer, NavBar, CenterBoxComponent } from "@/components";
import ThemeRegistry from "@/components/appProvider/themeRegistry";
import { WagmiProvider } from "wagmi";
import { config } from "@/config/wagmi";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import useGapiLoader from "@/components/calendarGroup/useGoogleApiLoader";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  useGapiLoader(
    "AIzaSyCoitOBVLgc4s7Yv1k4XhN8RZnbtEqYuFQ",
    "168889487717-0lc3lga0ohk3e4isdug6171licjffc0b.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"],
    "https://www.googleapis.comauth/calendar.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
    () => {
      console.log("API LOADED");
    }
  );

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" async defer></script>
      </head>
      <body style={{ height: "100vh", margin: 0 }}>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <WagmiProvider config={config}>
            <ThemeRegistry>
              <NavBar />
              <CenterBoxComponent>{children}</CenterBoxComponent>
              <Footer />
            </ThemeRegistry>
          </WagmiProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default RootLayout;

I also tried using 'useQuery()' like this:

const useGoogleCalendarApi = () => {
  const calendarData = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["google-calendar-api-events"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      try {

        return "TEST";

      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error fetching events: ", e);
      }
    },
  });

  return calendarData;
};

export default useGoogleCalendarApi;

